# How to get ex or em equivalent in math display mode

Tags: fontsize, displaystyle

Based on the following output, it appears to me that changing to \displaystyle or \scriptstyle does not actually change the font size as represented by \f@size. It also does not appear to change the ex or em values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
Display style $\displaystyle \f@size pt$.

text style $\textstyle \f@size pt$.

script style $\scriptstyle \f@size pt$.

scriptscript style $\scriptscriptstyle \f@size pt$.

small $\small\f@size pt$.

tiny $\tiny\f@size pt$.

large $\large\f@size pt$.
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to define a macro using \mathchoice that displays a tikz picture that is appropriately scaled, and I need access to something like ex or em for the font size that is actually being used, depending on the math display style.

**Question.** How do I get access to the current font size being used for the current math display style?

Comment: simplest is to use `\text{\begin{tizpicture....}` and then the ams `\text` macro takes care of this and gives you a matching text font setup.

Comment: That totally works! Please post your comment as an answer, and I will accept. I was able to avoid \mathchoice this way, simply by using ex unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be simpler to use `\text{\begin{tizpicture....}` and then the AMS `\text` macro takes care of this and gives you a matching text font setup